# Is there a way to do multi-line input in ruby AND single-line input at the same time (conditional user input)?

Tags: ruby

I face the following problem:

I have an irb-like shell where a user can give instructions.

For this I read in user input, both via Readline if the Readline
module is available, or through default $stdin.gets.

By default $stdin.gets will end at a \n character, if the user
hit enter. This works fine for most cases, but now I have the
problem that a user must be allowed to input a "'" character.
If you can not see this character, I literally mean the '
apostrophe right above the '#' character on most keyboards.

If he does so, then the record separator must change to "'" to,
so that the user can do multiline input.

The reason is that the desired input shall be something like:

```
data '
foo
bar
bla
'
```

Whereas normally it would be:

```
data foo
data far
data bla
```

Which is fine for single-line assignment, but not good for 
multiline assignment as nobody wants to preface via "data" 
on each line, hence why I want the "'" character to be the
delimiter in ONLY this case, otherwise default to \n newline.

It could be any other character too by the way, I just need
conditional user input.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
$/ = "'"
user_input = STDIN.gets
puts user_input
```

It's not the same as what you wanted but it will continue taking inputs until you give the apostrophe mark.